# How to make cuda-memcheck return non zero when there is a leak check error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, memory-leaks, cuda

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 7.5. Suppose I have the simple code

```
int main()
{
  float *test;

  cudaMallocManaged(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&test), 100 * sizeof(float),
                    cudaMemAttachGlobal);

  cudaDeviceReset();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it with

```
cuda-memcheck --leak-check full ./Test
```

Obviously there will be leak error because I didn't free the memory, but when I type

```
echo $?
```

immediately after running the memcheck, it shows

```
0
```

indicating success even when there actually are errors. What can I do to make cuda-memcheck to return non zero when there is actually leak errors? This is important for unit testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#command-line-options) indicates that to get a non-zero error return from `cuda-memcheck`, it's necessary to specify the `--error-exitcode ?` option, where `?` is replaced by the desired (non-zero) value that will be returned if an error is identified by cuda-memcheck.  Here's a fully worked sequence using your example:

```
$ cat t23.cu
int main()
{
  float *test;

  cudaMallocManaged(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&test), 100 * sizeof(float),
                    cudaMemAttachGlobal);

  cudaDeviceReset();

  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t23 t23.cu
$ cuda-memcheck --leak-check full --error-exitcode 1 ./t23
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Leaked 400 bytes at 0x600000000
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at cudaMalloc time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuMemAllocManaged + 0x193) [0x13eb73]
=========     Host Frame:./t23 [0x2f125]
=========     Host Frame:./t23 [0xc3a1]
=========     Host Frame:./t23 [0x3f6f0]
=========     Host Frame:./t23 [0x269e]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21d65]
=========     Host Frame:./t23 [0x2589]
=========
========= LEAK SUMMARY: 400 bytes leaked in 1 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ echo $?
1
$
```

You can also find mention of the `error-exitcode` command line option in the command line help (`cuda-memcheck --help`):

```
$ cuda-memcheck --help |grep exitcode
 --error-exitcode <number> [Default : 0]
                       When this is set, memcheck will return the given exitcod  when any errors are detected
$
```